# Fill SQL database from a CSV File

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I need to create a database using a CSV file with SSIS. The CSV file includes four columns:

[image]

I need to use the information of that table to populate the three tables I created in SQL below.

I have realized that what I need is to use one column of the Employee Table, `EmployeeNumber`, and Group Table, `GroupID`, to populate the EmployeeGroup table. For that, I thought that a Join Merge table is what I needed, but I created the Data Flow Task in SSIS, and the results are the same, no data displayed.

[image]

The middle table is the one used to relate the other tables.

I created the package in SSIS and the Employee and Group Tables are populated, but the  EmployeeGroup table is not. EmployeeGroup will only show the EmployeeNumber and Group ID columns with no data.

I am new using SSIS, and I really do not know what else to do. I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you try to do this all with one data flow?  You might need several.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to first populate your `Employee` and `Group` tables, and then - in another data flow, to run after the first - populate the `EmployeeGroup` table from a join between your initial data source and your `Group` table.

Comment: I would recommend loading your file to a staging table first and then querying the staging table to insert into your other tables.

Answer (score 11):

## Overview

1. *Solutions using SSIS*

   - *Using 3 Data Flow Tasks*
   - *Using 2 Data Flow Tasks*
2. *Solutions Using T-SQL*

   - *Using Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB*
   - *Using Microsoft Text Driver*
3. *Solutions Using PowerShell*

## 1st Solution - SSIS

### Using 3 Data Flow Tasks

*This can be done using only 2 Data Flow Task, but according to what the OP mentioned in the question `I am new using SSIS, and I really do not know what else to do`, i will provide easiest solution which is 3 DataFlow Task to avoid using more components like `MultiCast`.*

### Solution Overview

Because you want to build a relational database and extract relations from the csv, you have to read the csv 3 times *-consider it as 3 seperated files -*.

First you have to import Employees and Groups Data, Then you have to import the relation table between them.

Each Import step can be done in a seperate Data Flow Task

### Detailed Solution

1. Add a *Flat File connection Manager* (Csv File)
2. Add An *OLEDB connection Manager* (SQL Destination)
3. Add 3 *DataFlow Task* like the image below

[image]

#### First Data Flow Task

1. Add a *Flat File Source* , a *Script Component* , *OLEDB destination* like shown in the image below

[image]

2. In the *Script Component* choose Group Name column as Input

[image]

3. Select the *Output Buffer* and change `SynchronousInputID Property` to `None` And add an output column `OutGroupname` with type `DT_STR`

[image]

4. In the *Script* section write the following Code:

   ```
    Imports System.Collections.Generic

    Private m_List As New List(Of String)
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

   If Not Row.GroupName_IsNull AndAlso
           Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.GroupName.Trim) Then

       If Not m_List.Contains(Row.GroupName.Trim) Then

           m_List.Add(Row.GroupName.Trim)

           CreateOutputRows(Row.GroupName.Trim)

       End If


   End If
   End Sub

   Public Sub CreateOutputRows(ByVal strValue As String)


   Output0Buffer.AddRow()
   Output0Buffer.OutGroupName = strValue
   End Sub
   ```
5. On the *OLEDB Destination* map `OutGroupName` to `GroupName` Column

[image]

#### Second Data Flow Task : Import Employees Data

- Repeat the same steps done with `Groupname` Column : with a single difference that is you have to choose the `EmployeeID`, `Employee Name`, `LoginName` columns as Input in the *Script Component* and Use the `ID` Column instead of `Groupname` column in the comparaison

#### Third Data Flow Task : Import Employees_Group Data

1. You have to add a *Flat File Source* , *Look Up transformation* , *OLEDB Destination*

[image]

2. In The *LookUp Transformation* Component select `Groups` Table as a Lookup table
3. Map `GroupName` Columns and Get `Group ID` as output

[image]

4. Choose `Ignore Failure` in the *Error Output* Configuration
5. In *Oledb Destination* map columns as following

[image]

*Note: `GroupID` must be an Identity (set it in sql server)*

### Using 2 Data Flow Tasks

*You have to do the same steps as the 3 Data Flow Tasks solution, but instead of adding 2 Data Flow Tasks to `Group` and `Employee`, just add one Data Flow Task, and after the `Flat File Source` add a `MultiCast` component to duplicate the Flow. Then for the first flow use the same `Script Component` and `OLEDB Destination` used in the `Employee` Data Flow Task, and for the second flow use the `Script Component` and `OLEDB Destination` related to `Group`.*

---

## 2nd Solution - Using TSQL

There are many method to import Flat file to SQL via T-SQL commands

### OPENROWSET with Microsoft ACE OLEDB provider

*Assuming that the installed version of Microsoft ACE OLEDB is `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` and that the csv file location is `C:\abc.csv`*

1. *First Import data into Employee and Group Table*

   ```
   INSERT INTO [GROUP]
       ([Group Name])
   SELECT 
       [Group Name] 
   FROM 
       OPENROWSET
           (
               'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\;IMEX=1;','SELECT * FROM abc.csv'
           ) t


   INSERT INTO [Employee]
       ([Employee Number],[Employee Name],[LoginName])
   SELECT 
       [Employee Number],[Employee Name],[LoginName] 
   FROM 
       OPENROWSET
           (
               'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\;IMEX=1;','SELECT * FROM abc.csv'
           ) t
   ```
2. *Import the Employee_Group Data*

   ```
   INSERT INTO [EmployeeGroup]
       ([Employee Number],[GroupID])
   SELECT 
       t1.[Employee Number],t2.[GroupID]
   FROM 
       OPENROWSET
           (
               'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\;IMEX=1;','SELECT * FROM abc.csv'
           ) t1 INNER JOIN GROUP t2 ON t1.[Group Name] = T2.[Group Name]
   ```

### OPENROWSET with Microsoft Text Driver

1. *First Import data into Employee and Group Table*

   ```
   INSERT INTO [GROUP]
       ([Group Name])
   SELECT 
       [Group Name] 
   FROM 
       OPENROWSET
           (
               'MSDASQL',
               'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
               DefaultDir=C:\;',
               'SELECT * FROM abc.csv'
           ) t


   INSERT INTO [Employee]
       ([Employee Number],[Employee Name],[LoginName])
   SELECT 
       [Employee Number],[Employee Name],[LoginName] 
   FROM 
       OPENROWSET
           (
               'MSDASQL',
               'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
               DefaultDir=C:\;',
               'SELECT * FROM abc.csv'
           ) t
   ```
2. *Import the Employee_Group Data*

   ```
   INSERT INTO [EmployeeGroup]
       ([Employee Number],[GroupID])
   SELECT 
       t1.[Employee Number],t2.[GroupID]
   FROM 
       OPENROWSET
           (
               'MSDASQL',
               'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
               DefaultDir=C:\;',
               'SELECT * FROM abc.csv'
           ) t1 INNER JOIN GROUP t2 ON t1.[Group Name] = T2.[Group Name]
   ```

*Note: You can Import Data to a staging table, then query this table, to avoid connecting many times to the csv File*

---

## Solutions Using PowerShell

There are many method to import csv files to SQL server, you can check the following links for additional informations.

- [Four Easy Ways to Import CSV Files to SQL Server with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/28/four-easy-ways-to-import-csv-files-to-sql-server-with-powershell/)
- [How to import data from .csv in SQL Server using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539179/how-to-import-data-from-csv-in-sql-server-using-powershell)

---

## References

- [OPENROWSET (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql)
- [T-SQL – Read CSV files using OpenRowSet](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2015/02/09/t-sql-read-csv-files-using-openrowset)
- [Import error using Openrowset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883658/import-error-using-openrowset/41945440#41945440)

Comment: Why not add a third option Powershell?

Comment: @MarkKram i don't have a good experience in Powershell, but i am interesting to see how it can be done. If you know it plz write an answer. and i will upvote it surely

Comment: @MarkKram i added some helpful links about importing csv to sql-server using powershell to my answer.

Comment: With Powershell (PoSh) you can leverage the .Net framework (think CLR) within a scripting environment.  You can also run the PoSh script natively in an SQL Agent job. I use it all the time to import CSV, Excel, and Access data. It's very powerful and simply to use.

Comment: @MarkKram why not posting a powershell detailed answer?

Comment: Well mainly is that I don't have access to a computer right now and it is too much typing on a cell phone. There are quite a few examples on this site.

Comment: @MarkKram That's ok. I list it in my answer. If the OP want to use it. He can access to the links i added. Thx for the remark

Comment: What an effort you put into your answer +1

Comment: @plaidDK thanx, i really appreciate that

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest solution would be to import the csv to a flat staging table and then use some `insert into...select` statements to populate the target tables.
Assuming you know how to import to a flat table, the rest is quite simple:

```
INSERT INTO Employee (EmployeeNumber, EmployeeName, LoginName)
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeNumber, EmployeeName, LoginName
FROM Stage

INSERT INTO [Group] (GroupName)
SELECT DISTINCT GroupName 
FROM Stage

INSERT INTO EmployeeGroup(EmployeeNumber, GroupId)
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeNumber, GroupId
FROM Stage s
INNER JOIN [Group] g ON s.GroupName = g.GroupName
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/KYSRAV27706)

Answer (score 3):

Since you already know how to import the csv and extract two tables (Employee and Group), I suggest you just populate EmployeeGroup in the same way. And stop using a group_id. If you do that, you'll get sql statements like:

```
select [Employee Number], [Employee Name], LoginName from Employee
select [Group Name] from Employee
select distinct [Employee Number], [Group Name] from Employee
```

Most likely, you'll have similar statements already working for Employee and Group. In this option you can make it work in the same way, without using a Join Merge. It's a usefull option, but clearly somewhere in that component something goes wrong.