# Import error using Openrowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, csv

I am trying to import a column (from .csv file) with numeric and alphanumeric values but when I run the `openrowset` procedure it imports the numeric rows properly but for alphanumeric values it defaults to `null`.

*Table A*

```
ID,A,B,C
1,12,hh,i
2,ab12,tt,b
3,2,aa,o
4,bc12,ee,l
```

*Code used*

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    OPENROWSET
        (
            'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\;IMEX=1;','SELECT * FROM abc.csv'
        ) t
```

I used `IMEX =1` and no change at all.

Comment: why not accepting the answer provided it is 100% correct?

Comment: Did you solved the issue? Why not giving feedback on the answer below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The problem cause is  the Oledb provider**

When importing csv file or excel files with mixed data types column it will replace non dominant types by `null`. (*Using Oledb or Ace.Oledb*)

**Workarounds**

You can do some workaround by adding a first row that contain string values then removing it after impirting is finish

```
ID,A,B,C
0,a,a,a
1,12,hh,i
2,ab12,tt,b
3,2,aa,o
4,bc12,ee,l
```

And it will fix the issue if using `IMEX=1`

This will read columns as string and ID column as number. (0 is used)

Or add `HDR=NO` property to connection string so the header is the first line imported (all its values are strings)

Read more about mixed data types in this [article](https://www.google.com.lb/amp/s/munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/12/15/importing-data-from-excel-having-mixed-data-types-in-a-column-ssis/amp/)

**Other methods**

Or try to achieve this without aceoledb provider just import csv file in other way like the following:

**Using Microsoft Text Driver**

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',
'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
DefaultDir=C:\;',
'SELECT * FROM abc.csv')
```

**Using BULK INSERT**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable 
(ID INTEGER,
 A VARCHAR(50),
 B VARCHAR(50),
 C VARCHAR(50)
)

BULK INSERT dbo.MyTable
FROM 'C:\abc.csv'
WITH 
  (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
  )
```

Other Details in these articles:

- [How to import csv file with OPENROWSET?](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2008/import-csv/)
- [T-SQL – Read CSV files using OpenRowSet](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2015/02/09/t-sql-read-csv-files-using-openrowset) *(A detailed tutorial)*

Comment: I want to automate the process every time opening writing and saving is not a feasible option.

Comment: @zack read the article that i provided i think it is what ur looking for

Comment: No then I wont have column names I will have F1,F2 and etc which isnt acceptable.

Comment: @zack why down voting? Read more about oledb mixed data types and you will see that there is only few ways to work with.

Comment: `OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)".` getting this error when I use above process

Comment: Please follow these steps:

Go to Control Panel -- Administrative Tools -- Data Sources(ODBC) --Drivers

check if there is a driver named "Microsoft Text Driver".

Comment: @Zack you can also follow this link for more details https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2015/02/09/t-sql-read-csv-files-using-openrowset

Answer (score 4):

The below example should work. Note that On my system I couldn't use the provider that you use (because I haven't installed this in a while and figuring out what to install is driving me crazy.) The key piece: You need a format file to tell SQL server the expected values in each column.  Here's a good blog post 
[using csv in your queries](http://blog.hubacek.uk/use-your-text-csv-files-in-your-queries-via-openrowset/)
 I can't paste the XMl as the version may vary depending on your database:

The easiest way to create the xml file is to:

1) Create a table in the database. You won't be inserting to this. It will just allow you to have the next command create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestInsert 
(ID INTEGER,
 A VARCHAR(10),
 B VARCHAR(10),
 C VARCHAR(10)
)
```

2) Next, run the following command line bcp program to generate the appropriate file:

```
bcp YourDatabase.dbo.TestInsert format nul -c -x -fimport.xml -t, -T
```

3) Finally, use import.xml as your format file.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
   OPENROWSET
    (
        BULK 'c:\test.csv', 
        FORMATFILE='c:\import.xml',
        FIRSTROW=2
    ) t
```