# SQL JOIN on varchar with special characters and leading zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, openrowset

I have a problem with join on `varchar` column.

I'm going to update SQL data from Excel data by product code but `Twr_Kod` is `varchar` and it is the only way to join with Excel data.

There is also problem with convert to varchar when there are leading zeros.

```
select CDN.Towary.Twr_Kod, excel.Twr_Kod 
from CDN.Towary 
left join openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                     Excel 8.0;Database=C:\excel\towary.xlsx;',
                     'select * from [Arkusz1$]') excel 
                  on cast(CDN.Towary.Twr_Kod as varchar) = cast(excel.Twr_Kod as varchar)
```

[image]

I know it is not a good solution to join on varchar column but it's necessary so please help why *cast* is not converting.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server` please tag your question correctly.

Comment: Sorry, changed. Only sql-server

Comment: please give some example values with leading zeros and highlight the problem, you haven't shown that in your sample data

Comment: Here is Excel file with join result [link]http://www50.zippyshare.com/v/HFp71lW4/file.html

Comment: please don't share files like this, nobody want's to click a link to download an excel file off some random person off the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because your excel column contains mixed data types. *When importing csv file or excel files with mixed data types column it will replace non dominant types by null. (Using Oledb or Ace.Oledb)*

**Workaround**

Add `IMEX=1;` to your openrowset connectionstring and add a dummy first row containning text values

Follow my answer at [Import error using Openrowset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883658/import-error-using-openrowset/41945440#41945440) to get more details

Comment: It's so confusing but working. Thank you so much. You saved my life :D