# SQL Server 2012 ACE.OLEDB.12.0 from CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, oledb

I'm trying to use next code to import data from CSV file:

```
 select * FROM OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Text;Database=C:\Users\Evgeny\Desktop;HDR=Yes;FORMAT=Delimited(;)', 
    'SELECT * FROM [test.csv]'
);
```

And my data have next structure, where 1st string has column names:

```
"Name1";"Name2";"Name3"
"Value1";"Value2";"Value3"
```

But after the query is executed, the result is only one column, like this:

```
Name1
Value1
```

What can be a problem?
How can I solve it not usung other drivers, becouse on my job place I can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `OPENROWSET` with `BULK`

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK 'FILE.csv',
SINGLE_CLOB) AS DATA;
```

Or use Microsoft Text Driver:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5869d247-f0a0-4224-80b3-ff2e414be402/how-to-read-csv-file-in-sql-server-2005-using-openrowset-function?forum=sqldataaccess

You can also follow my answer at [Import error using Openrowset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883658/import-error-using-openrowset/41945440#41945440) it may helps you

Comment: thank you. But now the simplest way is to save file as .xlsx=(

Comment: I didn't understand you. Are you asking to import xlsx or csv

Comment: if you follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883658/import-error-using-openrowset/41945440#41945440 you will find that using oledb provider from importing csv is not best practice. because when importing a column that contain multiple data types it will cause problems

Comment: the problem is that with csv it does not work, but when you convert file to .xlsx ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for excel 12.0 it works properly and will be no " characters.