# Get data from Excel, csv into SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server-2017

What is the best solution to transfer Excel and csv data from files to SQL Server tables and use trigger to automate it to other tables?

Comment: Check the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938557/fill-sql-database-from-a-csv-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest way would be to create an SSIS job for reading the excel/csv files run it via the Sql Server Agents. You can find details here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017

SQL statement for importing excel file

```
SELECT * INTO Data_dq
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=D:\Desktop\Data.xlsx', [Data$]);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017

For CSV files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-flat-file-wizard?view=sql-server-2017