# Importing data from CSV files into SQL Server with additional column using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv

I would like to import data from my CSV files using PowerShell.
The answer posted here:
[How to import data from .csv in SQL Server using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539179/how-to-import-data-from-csv-in-sql-server-using-powershell)
works like a charm.

However, I'd like to build on this solution. If the files contain 2 columns, e.g. Feature1, Feature2, I'd like the table to have a third column e.g. Name. The aim is to load multiple files corresponding to different Names into a single table.

```
Feature1 | Feature2 | Name
Value1   | Value2   | NameA
Value3   | Value4   | NameA
...
Value5   | Value6   | NameB
```

If I give PowerShell the variable

```
$NameValue = "NameA"
```

How do I include this correctly in the command:

```
Import-CSV .\NameA.csv | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd `
  -Database $database -ServerInstance $server `
  -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.Feature1)','$($_.Feature2)', '$($NameValue.Name)')"
  }
```

Currently, this just fills in the Feature columns, but the Name column is blank.

Comment: just `$NameValue`

Comment: Thanks. That worked. It does require the quotes however, which I think is what I missed when I initially tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (you shouldn't need to use the subexpression `$()` operator unless you're accessing the property of a variable from within a string):

```
Import-CSV .\NameA.csv | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd `
  -Database $database -ServerInstance $server `
  -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.Feature1)','$($_.Feature2)', '$NameValue')"
}
```