# PowerShell. Group-object usage in one file

Tags: powershell, group-object

I am trying to combine several rows into one, provided that the key cell is the same. And write data from all lines with the same key to the final line.

[Example Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKT6N.png)

```
**Before**  

ID      |  Name |  DateTime            | Duration |     Call_Type   |
1234509 |  Mike | 2020-01-02T01:22:33  |          |     Start_Call  |
1234509 |       | 2020-01-02T01:32:33  |  600     |     End_call    |
```

**AFTER**

```
ID      |  Name |  DateTime            | Duration |     Start_Call     |  End_call             | 
1234509 |  Mike |  2020-01-02T01:22:33 |     600  |2020-01-02T01:22:33 |  2020-01-02T01:32:33  |
```

Before

```
ID;Name;DateTime;Duration;Call_Type
1234509;Mike;2020-01-02T01:22:33;;Start_Call
1234509;;2020-01-02T01:32:33;600;End_call
```

After

```
ID;Name;Duration;Start_Call;End_call
1234509;Mike;600;2020-01-02T01:22:33;2020-01-02T01:32:33
```

How to use here

```
$csv | Group-Object ID
```

and get the data as in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by `ID` with [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7), you can iterate each group and create a new [`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0) with the properties you want to export in your output CSV file.

For `ID` we simply use the grouping key. `Name` and `Duration` we choose the first object that doesn't have a `$null` or empty version of that property using [`System.String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8). For `Start_Call` and `End_Call` we choose the object that has those values for the `Call_Type` property.

The filtering is done by [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7). To get the first and expanded versions of the properties, we also use `-First` and `-ExpandProperty` from [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7#parameters).

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path .\data.csv -Delimiter ";"

$groups = $csv | Group-Object -Property ID

& {
    foreach ($group in $groups)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ID = $group.Name
            Name = $group.Group | Where-Object {-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Name)} | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name
            Duration = $group.Group | Where-Object {-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Duration)} | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Duration
            Start_Call = $group.Group | Where-Object {$_.Call_Type -eq "Start_Call"} | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty DateTime
            End_Call = $group.Group | Where-Object {$_.Call_Type -eq "End_Call"} | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty DateTime
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\output.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

**output.csv**

```
"ID";"Name";"Duration";"Start_Call";"End_Call"
"1234509";"Mike";"600";"2020-01-02T01:22:33";"2020-01-02T01:32:33"
```

If you want to remove quotes from the CSV file, you can use the `-UseQuotes` switch from [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7#parameters). However, yhis does require **PowerShell 7**. If your using a lower PowerShell version, you can use some of the recommendations from [How to remove all quotations mark in the csv file using powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678901/how-to-remove-all-quotations-mark-in-the-csv-file-using-powershell-script).