# Check csv file values against every line in another csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two csv file where I contain data, I need to check if value from CSV 1 exist in CSV 2 and if so then replace this value in file2 with data from file1, if no just skip to another row,

File1.csv

```
NO;Description
L001;DREAM
L002;CAR
L003;PHONE
L004;HOUSE
L005;PLANE
```

File2.csv

```
ID;Name;Status*;Scheduled Start Date;Actual Start Date;Actual End Date;Scheduled End Date;SLA
144862;DREAM;Scheduled;1524031200;;;1524033000;
149137;CAR;Implementation In Progress;1528588800;;;1548968400;
150564;PHONE;Scheduled;1569456000;;;1569542400;
150564;HOUSE;Scheduled;1569456000;;;1569542400;
150564;PLANE;;;;;;
```

I tried something like that but it is not working for me:

```
    $file1 = Import-Csv "C:\Users\file1.csv" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description
$file2 = Import-Csv "C:\Users\file1.csv" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty NO
        Import-Csv "C:\Users\file3.csv" |Where-Object {$file1 -like $_.Name} |ForEach-Object {
          $_.Name = $file2($_.NO)
    } |Out-File "C:\Users\File4.csv"
```

File4.csv should like that:

```
ID;Name;Status*;Scheduled Start Date;Actual Start Date;Actual End Date;Scheduled End Date;SLA
144862;L001;Scheduled;1524031200;;;1524033000;
149137;L002;Implementation In Progress;1528588800;;;1548968400;
150564;L003;Scheduled;1569456000;;;1569542400;
150564;L004;Scheduled;1569456000;;;1569542400;
150564;L005;;;;;;
```

Maybe there is another way to achive my goal! Thank you

Comment: Why is there an asterisk in the `Status` column? Is that for real or a typo when posting?

Comment: This is how file is exported, it is not typo error, but this column is not using to check values so it shouldnt be a problem, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach you can take:

- Import both CSV files with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7)
- Create a lookup hash table from the first CSV file, where the `Description` you want to replace are the keys, and `NO` are the values.
- Go through the second CSV file, and replace any values from the `Name` column from the hash table, if the key exists. We can use [`System.Collections.Hashtable.ContainsKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.containskey?view=netframework-4.8) to check if the key exists. This is a constant time `O(1)` operation, so lookups are fast.
- Then we can export the final CSV with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7). I used `-UseQuotes Never` to put no `"` quotes in your output file. This feature is only available in **PowerShell 7**. For lower PowerShell versions, you can have a look at [How to remove all quotations mark in the csv file using powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678901/how-to-remove-all-quotations-mark-in-the-csv-file-using-powershell-script) for other alternatives to removing quotes from a CSV file.

**Demo:**

```
$csvFile1 = Import-Csv -Path .\File1.csv -Delimiter ";"
$csvFile2 = Import-Csv -Path .\File2.csv -Delimiter ";"

$ht = @{}
foreach ($item in $csvFile1) {
    if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($item.Description)) {
        $ht[$item.Description] = $item.NO
    }
}

& {
    foreach ($line in $csvFile2) {
        if ($ht.ContainsKey($line.Name)) {
            $line.Name = $ht[$line.Name]
        }
        $line
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path File4.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never
```

Or instead of wrapping the `foreach` loop inside a script block using the [`Call Operator &`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#call-operator-), we can use [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7). You can have a look at [`about_script_blocks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7) for more information about script blocks.

```
$csvFile2 | ForEach-Object {
    if ($ht.ContainsKey($_.Name)) {
        $_.Name = $ht[$_.Name]
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv -Path File4.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never
```

**File4.csv**

```
ID;Name;Status*;Scheduled Start Date;Actual Start Date;Actual End Date;Scheduled End Date;SLA
144862;L001;Scheduled;1524031200;;;1524033000;
149137;L002;Implementation In Progress;1528588800;;;1548968400;
150564;L003;Scheduled;1569456000;;;1569542400;
150564;L004;Scheduled;1569456000;;;1569542400;
150564;L005;;;;;;
```

---

**Update**

For handling multiple values with the same `Name`, we can transform the above to use a hash table of [`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0), where we have two properties `Count` to keep track of the current item we're seeing and `NO` which is an array of numbers:

```
$csvFile1 = Import-Csv -Path .\File1.csv -Delimiter ";"
$csvFile2 = Import-Csv -Path .\File2.csv -Delimiter ";"

$ht = @{}
foreach ($row in $csvFile1) {
    if (-not $ht.ContainsKey($row.Description) -and 
        -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($item.Description)) {
        $ht[$row.Description] = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Count = 0
            NO = @()
        }
    }
    $ht[$row.Description].NO += $row.NO
}

& {
    foreach ($line in $csvFile2) {
        if ($ht.ContainsKey($line.Name)) {
            $name = $line.Name
            $pos = $ht[$name].Count
            $line.Name = $ht[$name].NO[$pos]
            $ht[$name].Count += 1
        }
        $line
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path File4.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never
```

Comment: I don't what to do wrong but this part is not working for me 
`$csvFile2 | ForEach-Object {
    if ($ht.ContainsKey($_.Name)) {
        $_.Name = $ht[$_.Name]
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv -Path File4.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes Never`

Comment: @majan What is the error your getting? Works fine for me.

Comment: my files are big and contains sometimes in File1.csv empty value in Description Column, is there any way to skip if there is no value. I do somethng wrong with second option of code probalby

Comment: @majan I've added a check to make sure no `$null` or empty values are added with `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty`. The row of the second file will only get updated if a key is found in `$ht` using `ContainsKey`.

Comment: ok, I have last polite request, sometimes in file1.csv I have multiple instance of same description but another number of it, 
`NO;Description
L001;DREAM
L002;CAR
L005;PLANE
L011;DREAM
L111;DREAM` 
right now only first attemp is adding into file2, how I can add each attemp. The best would be copy whole row and add new ID like 
`ID;Name;Status*;Scheduled Start Date;Actual Start Date;Actual End Date;Scheduled End Date;SLA
144862;L001;Scheduled;1524031200;;;1524033000;
144862;L011;Scheduled;1524031200;;;1524033000;
144862;L111;Scheduled;1524031200;;;1524033000;` I hope you get it

Comment: @majan I understand. I'll add that in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212343/discussion-between-roadrunner-and-majan).

Answer (score 0):

If your files aren't too big, you could do this with a simple ForEach-Object loop:

```
$csv1   = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\File1.csv' -Delimiter ';'
$result = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\File2.csv' -Delimiter ';' | 
          ForEach-Object {
              $name = $_.Name
              $item = $csv1 | Where-Object { $_.Description -eq $name } | Select-Object -First 1
              # update the Name property and output the item
              if ($item) { 
                $_.Name = $item.NO
                # if you output the row here, the result wil NOT contain rows that did not match
                # $_   
              }
              # if on the other hand, you would like to retain the items that didn't match unaltered,
              # then output the current row here
              $_
          }

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

#output to new CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\File4.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen:

```
ID     Name Status*                    Scheduled Start Date Actual Start Date Actual End Date Scheduled End Date SLA
--     ---- -------                    -------------------- ----------------- --------------- ------------------ ---
144862 L001 Scheduled                  1524031200                                             1524033000            
149137 L002 Implementation In Progress 1528588800                                             1548968400            
150564 L003 Scheduled                  1569456000                                             1569542400            
150564 L004 Scheduled                  1569456000                                             1569542400            
150564 L005
```

Comment: files are really big, but don't know but your code is not working

Comment: @majan it works for me, but in your question you never explained it involves large files. What is "not working"?