# check names in a folder and delete double quotes in a csv using a powershell loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, while-loop, file-get-contents, foreach-object

I'm trying to loop on files in a specific folder and delete double quotes in them

anyone could explain this ,I did this :

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\test\" -filter SplitCSV* | 

    ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_) -replace '(?m)"([^,]*?)"(?=,|$)', '$1' | Set-Content $_   }
```

With this error message :

```
Get-Content : Impossible de trouver le chemin d'accès «
C:\Users\cptspinstalldev\SplitCSV_03-08-2020_9.csv», car il n'existe pas.
```

So I moved my files in C:\Users\cptspinstalldev\ and it worked but why did my get-childitems didn't look in the right folder which is c:\temp\test\

Looks like I was not in the right folder so dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is unsafe to delete all quotes in existing CSV files, please consider using my function [ConvertTo-CsvNoQuotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60681762/9898643) to do that for you.

Add the function on top of your script and do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp\test" -Filter 'SplitCSV*.csv' -File | 
    ForEach-Object {
        (Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName) | ConvertTo-CsvNoQuotes | Set-Content $_.FullName
    }
```

If you're on PowerShell 7.0, you can do without that function and simply code as

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp\test" -Filter 'SplitCSV*.csv' -File | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_.FullName
        (Import-Csv -Path $file) | Export-Csv -Path $file -UseQuotes AsNeeded
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell the `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` functions expect a full path. The `$_` variable is a `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo` object. Try to pass in the full path using `$_.FullName`, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\test\" -filter SplitCSV* | 

ForEach-Object {
(Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace '(?m)"([^,]*?)"(?=,|$)', '$1' | Set-Content $_.FullName   }
```

Comment: Your description _The $_ variable contains only the file name (without directory)_ is wrong. The `$_` automatic variable inside the loop represents either a `FileInfo` or a `DirectoryInfo` **object**. Because this is an object, it has properties like `FullName` etc.