# Extracting the key-value pair in loop from text file using Powershell Script

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, key-value

I am trying to capture the specific key value pairs from a text file having other data as well than key:value pattern using powershell. Can anyone help me out? I have tried the code so far with the help of internet as I am newbie to Powershell. Any help will be appreciated.

Source Text sample:

```
ResourceGroupName    : DataLake-Gen2
DataFactoryName      : dna-production-gen2
TriggerName          : TRG_RP_Optimizely_Import
TriggerRunId         : 08586050680855766354964895535CU57
TriggerType          : ScheduleTrigger
TriggerRunTimestamp  : 8/4/2020 10:59:59 AM
Status               : Succeeded
TriggeredPipelines   : {[PL_DATA_OPTIMIZELY_MART, 1f89fc3a-27b5-442e-9685-a444f751f607]}
Message              :
Properties           : {[TriggerTime, 8/4/2020 10:59:59 AM], [ScheduleTime, 8/4/2020 11:00:00 AM], [triggerObject, {
                         "name": "Trigger_421B8CAF-BE66-42CF-83DA-E3028693F304",
                         "startTime": "2020-08-04T10:59:59.8982174Z",
                         "endTime": "2020-08-04T10:59:59.8982174Z",
                         "scheduledTime": "2020-08-04T11:00:00Z",
                         "trackingId": "fdf58bb2-ecd5-4fe9-b2ef-d94fd71729c3",
                         "clientTrackingId": "08586050680855766354964895535CU57",
                         "originHistoryName": "08586050680855766354964895535CU57",
                         "code": "OK",
                         "status": "Succeeded"
                       }]}
AdditionalProperties : {[groupId, 08586050680855766354964895535CU57]}

ResourceGroupName    : DataLake-Gen2
DataFactoryName      : dna-production-gen2
TriggerName          : TRG_RP_Optimizely_Import
TriggerRunId         : 08586049816852049265494275953CU24
TriggerType          : ScheduleTrigger
TriggerRunTimestamp  : 8/5/2020 11:00:00 AM
Status               : Succeeded
TriggeredPipelines   : {[PL_DATA_OPTIMIZELY_MART, dd6b5beb-b7f6-44ef-8903-34c845003dfc]}
Message              :
Properties           : {[TriggerTime, 8/5/2020 11:00:00 AM], [ScheduleTime, 8/5/2020 11:00:00 AM], [triggerObject, {
                         "name": "Trigger_421B8CAF-BE66-42CF-83DA-E3028693F304",
                         "startTime": "2020-08-05T11:00:00.2662252Z",
                         "endTime": "2020-08-05T11:00:00.2662252Z",
                         "scheduledTime": "2020-08-05T11:00:00Z",
                         "trackingId": "ba223bbd-8cb2-40e8-951f-87130dbbbfe8",
                         "clientTrackingId": "08586049816852049265494275953CU24",
                         "originHistoryName": "08586049816852049265494275953CU24",
                         "code": "OK",
                         "status": "Succeeded"
                       }]}
AdditionalProperties : {[groupId, 08586049816852049265494275953CU24]}
```

Code used so far:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $path
)

function Format-LogFile {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        $log
    )

    $targets = 'TriggerRunTimestamp','ResourceGroupName', 'DataFactoryName', 'TriggerName', 'TriggerRunId', 'TriggerType', 'Status'
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$lines = @()
    $log | ForEach-Object {
        $line = $_
        $targets | ForEach-Object {
            if ($line.Contains($_) -and $line -notin $lines) {
                $lines.Add($line) | Out-Null
            }
        }
    }
#    $lines[0] = $lines[0].TrimStart("JournalSMS  ")
#    return $lines
    
}


function Get-LogFields {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (

        $lines
    )
    $targets = 'TriggerRunTimestamp','ResourceGroupName', 'DataFactoryName', 'TriggerName', 'TriggerRunId', 'TriggerType', 'Status'
    $matchs = $lines | Select-String -Pattern "(?<=(\s||\b))[A-Z][\s\[A-Z]/]+?\s*?\:\s+[^\s\b]+" -AllMatches 
    
    $dict = @{}
    $matchs.Matches | ForEach-Object {
        $val = $_.Value
        $arr = $val.Split("")
        if ($arr[0].Trim() -in $targets)  {
            $dict.Add($arr[0].Trim(), $arr[1].Trim())
        } 
    }
    
    return $dict
}


$log = get-content 'D:\\output.txt'
$path = "D:\\output.txt"
$info = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $path | ForEach-Object {
    $log = Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding Default
    $lines = Format-LogFile $log
    $dict = Get-LogFields $lines
    $values = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $dict
    return $values
} 



# $info |
# Select-Object   @{name='TriggerRunTimestamp';expression={$_.'TriggerRunTimestamp'}},
#                 @{name='ResourceGroupName';expression={$_."ResourceGroupName"}},
#                 @{name='DataFactoryName';expression={$_.'DataFactoryName'}},
#                 @{name='TriggerName';expression={$_.'TriggerName'}},
#                 @{name='TriggerRunId';expression={$_.'TriggerRunId'}} 
#                  @{name='TriggerType';expression={$_.'TriggerType'}}
#                 @{name='Status';expression={$_.'Status'}}|
# Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path .\result.csv -Force


$info |
Select-Object   'TriggerRunTimestamp', "ResourceGroupName", 'DataFactoryName',
                'TriggerName', 'TriggerRunId', 'TriggerType', 'Status' |
ConvertTo-CSV -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation |
% {$_.Replace('"','')} |
Set-Content -Path 'D:\\result.csv' -Force
# Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path .\result.csv -Force
```

**Expected Output:**

**TriggerRunTimestamp** **ResourceGroupName**   **DataFactoryName** **TriggerName** **TriggerRunId**    **TriggerType** **Status**  **TriggeredPipeline**   **Properties_TriggerTime**  **Properties_ScheduleTime** **triggerObject_name**  **triggerObject_startTime** **triggerObject_endTime**   **triggerObject_scheduledTime**
8/4/2020 10:59  DataLake-Gen2   dna-production-gen2 TRG_RP_Optimizely_Import    08586050680855766354964895535CU57   ScheduleTrigger Succeeded   PL_DATA_OPTIMIZELY_MART 8/4/2020 10:59  8/4/2020 11:00  Trigger_421B8CAF-BE66-42CF-83DA-E3028693F304    2020-08-04T10:59:59.8982174Z    2020-08-04T10:59:59.8982174Z    2020-08-04T11:00:00Z

NOTE: Bold values are the column headers and values are in plain text.

Help Much Needed !!

Thanks

Comment: I've centered my efforts around PSCustomObject, Get-Content with UTF-enconding, Hash-Tables and Arrays.. But would really appreciate some guidance

What I'm trying to do

- Recursively loop through Input Source Text File 

- Extract key-value pairs from the text file as mentioned in the code.

- And Export them as columns in a single CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic part in this log file is on property `Properties`, which is a JSON string. Luckily, you don't want any of this in your output CSV file, so the below should work:

```
# read the file as a single, multiline string using the -Raw switch
$log = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\the_input_log.txt' -Raw
# split the content into several blocks on the empty line, skip blocks that do not contain text
$result = ($log -split '(\r?\n){2,}' | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'}) | ForEach-Object {
    # split the block to get only the part with the properties you are interested in
    # replace ' : ' into an equals sign (mind the extra spaces around the colon, otherwise
    # you will also replace the colons in the 'TriggerRunTimestamp' property.

    # use ConvertFrom-StringData cmdlet to create a Hashtable from this and convert that to a PsCustomObject
    # finally, use Select-Object to output a new PSObject with only the properties you need in the wanted order.
    [PsCustomObject](($_ -split 'TriggeredPipelines')[0] -replace ' : ', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData)  |
    Select-Object 'TriggerRunTimestamp', 'ResourceGroupName', 'DataFactoryName', 'TriggerName', 'TriggerRunId', 'TriggerType', 'Status'
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\result.csv' -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

I have added quite a few comments in the code for you to hopefully make it understandable what is going on in there.

The resulting  CSV file **will** contain quotes:

```
"TriggerRunTimestamp","ResourceGroupName","DataFactoryName","TriggerName","TriggerRunId","TriggerType","Status"
"8/4/2020 10:59:59 AM","DataLake-Gen2","dna-production-gen2","TRG_RP_Optimizely_Import","08586050680855766354964895535CU57","ScheduleTrigger","Succeeded"
"8/5/2020 11:00:00 AM","DataLake-Gen2","dna-production-gen2","TRG_RP_Optimizely_Import","08586049816852049265494275953CU24","ScheduleTrigger","Succeeded"
```

If you absolutely do not want quotes and you are using PowerShell version 7, you can add `-UseQuotes AsNeeded` to the Export-Csv cmdlet.

For older PowerShell versions, you can use my function [ConvertTo-CsvNoQuotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60681762/9898643)

---

**Edit**

As per your comment, you also need properties from the (what *seemed to be* JSON) elements, you would need a completely different approach.

For the example you have given you can use:

```
# read the file as a single, multiline string using the -Raw switch
$log = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\the_input_log.txt' -Raw
# split the content into several blocks on the empty line, skip blocks that do not contain text
$result = ($log -split '(\r?\n){2,}' | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'}) | ForEach-Object {
    # create a Hashtable to store the key/value properties we find looping over each line in the block
    $hash = @{}
    switch -Regex ($_.Trim() -split '\r?\n') {
        '^(\w+)\s+:\s*(.*)' { $key = $matches[1]; $hash[$key] = $matches[2] }     # found a key/value property
        '^\s+(\S.+)'        { if ($key) {$hash[$key] += ("`r`n"+ $matches[1])} }  # add to a multiline property
    }
    # test if the above actually was able to parse 'TriggeredPipelines'
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($hash['TriggeredPipelines'])) {
    # remove the brackets from TriggeredPipelines
        $hash['TriggeredPipeline'] = ($hash['TriggeredPipelines'].Trim("{[]}") -split ',')[0]
    }

    # test if the above actually was able to parse 'Properties'
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($hash['Properties'])) {
        # the 'Properties' property needs a bit more work:
        # 1) remove the surrounding brackets, split into the first line and a textblock with the rest of the properties
        $props = $hash['Properties'].Trim("{[ ]}") -split '\r?\n', 2
        # $props[0] is now "[TriggerTime, 8/4/2020 10:59:59 AM], [ScheduleTime, 8/4/2020 11:00:00 AM], [triggerObject, {"
        # parse the TriggerTime and ScheduleTime from that line and add them to the hash
        $temp  = ([regex]'(?i)TriggerTime,\s*([^\]]+)').Matches($props[0]).Groups[1].Value
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($temp)) { $hash['Properties_TriggerTime'] = $temp }

        $temp = ([regex]'(?i)ScheduleTime,\s*([^\]]+)').Matches($props[0]).Groups[1].Value
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($temp)) { $hash['Properties_ScheduleTime'] = $temp }

        if ($props.Count -eq 2) {
            # 2) surround $props[1] with curly brackets, so it will become valid JSON and convert from that
            $props = '{{{0}}}' -f $props[1] | ConvertFrom-Json
            # loop through the properties and add these to the hash with "TriggerObject_" prefix
            foreach($p in $props.PSObject.Properties.name) {
                $hash["TriggerObject_$p"] = $props.$p
            }
        }
    }

    # final test to see if we have managed to capture anything
    # more strict but memory consuming would be 
    # if ($hash.Count -and ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace(-join $hash.Values)) {..}

    if ($hash.Count) {
        # convert the completed hash into a PSObject and select the properties you need from it
        [PsCustomObject]$hash | Select-Object 'TriggerRunTimestamp', 'ResourceGroupName', 'DataFactoryName',
                                              'TriggerName', 'TriggerRunId', 'TriggerType', 'Status', 
                                              'TriggeredPipeline', 'Properties_TriggerTime', 'Properties_ScheduleTime',
                                              'TriggerObject_name', 'TriggerObject_startTime', 
                                              'TriggerObject_endTime', 'TriggerObject_scheduledTime'
    }
}

# output on screen (won't fit as Table in the console)
$result

# write to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\result.csv' -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

The resulting CSV file will now look like

```
"TriggerRunTimestamp","ResourceGroupName","DataFactoryName","TriggerName","TriggerRunId","TriggerType","Status","TriggeredPipeline","Properties_TriggerTime","Properties_ScheduleTime","TriggerObject_name","TriggerObject_startTime","TriggerObject_endTime","TriggerObject_scheduledTime"
"8/4/2020 10:59:59 AM","DataLake-Gen2","dna-production-gen2","TRG_RP_Optimizely_Import","08586050680855766354964895535CU57","ScheduleTrigger","Succeeded","PL_DATA_OPTIMIZELY_MART","8/4/2020 10:59:59 AM","8/4/2020 11:00:00 AM","Trigger_421B8CAF-BE66-42CF-83DA-E3028693F304","2020-08-04T10:59:59.8982174Z","2020-08-04T10:59:59.8982174Z","2020-08-04T11:00:00Z"
"8/5/2020 11:00:00 AM","DataLake-Gen2","dna-production-gen2","TRG_RP_Optimizely_Import","08586049816852049265494275953CU24","ScheduleTrigger","Succeeded","PL_DATA_OPTIMIZELY_MART","8/5/2020 11:00:00 AM","8/5/2020 11:00:00 AM","Trigger_421B8CAF-BE66-42CF-83DA-E3028693F304","2020-08-05T11:00:00.2662252Z","2020-08-05T11:00:00.2662252Z","2020-08-05T11:00:00Z"
```

Comment: Thanks Theo for the updated script, but this the first step of the script ! Yes unfortunately I need some part of the "TriggeredPipelines" and "Properties", like from "properties" need 'Name', 'StartTime', 'EndTime', 'ScheduleTime' etc.                                                                It will loop through such data set in the "Source Sample" and will provide Datewise Data columns. I apologize for not able to explain earlier. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my required output as earlier I wasn't able to explain it properly. Can anyone help ?

Comment: @SaurabhShakyawar I have added new code to (more manually) get you the output you need.

Comment: Hi Theo, You are a savior ! The script works fine and giving the expected output with following errors and a Blank Row in the CSV file between the Header Column and First Actual Data Row and at the last of the CSV. Errors while running the scripts are as follows : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
Cannot index into a null array.

Comment: @SaurabhShakyawar Well... I only had your example to go on. If in real life the log file has extra empty lines or textlines in between that is what you can expect. I have just updated the code once more to hopefuly deal with that and it now tests everything before it will be added to the hash. Finally, it only outputs when there are properties captured, so you don't get empty lines in the CSV.

Comment: Thanks Theo ! I am now able to get the results expected and CSV file is looking good. I really appreciate your time and efforts ! Have a Great Day !

Answer (score 0):

[image: powershell-screenshot]

In PowerShell 5 ( I don't know about lower versions ). We can use -Match comparison to break a string having a pattern into "Key" and "Value" pair.
Mostly, the need comes when working with JSON objects.

---

```
PS C:\Users> $str = '"KeyStr": "ValueString"'
PS C:\Users> $str -match '(?<key>.+):(?<value>.+)'
True
PS C:\Users> # $Matches is inbuilt variable in PowerShell
PS C:\Users> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
key                            "KeyStr"
value                           "ValueString"
0                              "KeyStr": "ValueString"


PS C:\Users> $Matches.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object


PS C:\Users> $Matches.key
"KeyStr"
PS C:\Users> $Matches.Value
 "ValueString"
PS C:\Users>
------------------------------------------
```

For more help, check PowerShell help

"Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators"