# Powershell: How to delete quotes from string for csv Header

Tags: powershell, csv, quotes

I want to do the following:

```
$content = $source | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $HEADER
```

My problem is the Variable $HEADER. I use Get-Content to get the desired content. Unfortunately this adds quotes around the object, therefore -Header treats the list of columns as one column and ignores the commas.

If I echo $HEADER I get the following:
`"a","b","c"`

But it is treated as:
`'"a","b","c"'`

If I override $HEADER like this everything works:
`$HEADER = "a","b","c"`

Unfortunately I need to use Get-Content because my Header needs to be variable.

I believe `-remove "'", ""` only deletes characters in the string and not the surrounding quotes.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$header = '"a","b","c"';
$header = $header.Split(',');
```

`$HEADER = "a","b","c"` is an array, while `'"a","b","c"'` is a String.

So you should split it to get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content` (without switch `-Raw`) reads a text file as array of lines, so yes, then the header (and all remaining data) is not separated into fields.

`Import-Csv` will read and parse the input into **objects** with property names from the existing header or the headers you give it as string array using parameter `-Header`.

`Export-Csv` will always quote everything, be it a header or data field, unless you are using PowerShell version 7 and add `-UseQuotes AsNeeded` to the cmdlet.

Simply trying to remove all quotes in a CSV file is risking mis-alignment in the field order and rendering the csv as unusable. There is a safe way of doing this, see my function [ConvertTo-CsvNoQuotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60681762/9898643)