# Powershell: How to cleanly "deidentify" values in specific column

Tags: powershell, csv

I am looking for a clean way to deidentify values in a csv file's column. The way I was working on was kind of a hack with counting values etc and wanted to see if a more realistic way to approach this. The input would be similar to:

```
One~Two~Three~Four
Test One~Failed for account 999999999, UserId: 7777777, Error: Duplicate nickname~8abc-964863c382d8~3/11/2021 1:03:43 PM
Test One~Failed for account 121212121, UserId: 3434343, Error: Duplicate firstname~zzzz-964863c382d8~3/11/2021 1:04:43 PM
Test One~Failed for account 565656565, UserId: 7878787, Error: Duplicate firstname~yyyy-964863c382d8~3/11/2021 1:05:43 PM
```

And need the output to be like this, replacing the userId and account number with x's:

```
One~Two~Three~Four
Test One~Failed for account XXXXXXXXX, UserId: XXXXXXX, Error: Duplicate nickname~8abc-964863c382d8~3/11/2021 1:03:43 PM
Test One~Failed for account XXXXXXXXX, UserId: XXXXXXX, Error: Duplicate firstname~zzzz-964863c382d8~3/11/2021 1:04:43 PM
Test One~Failed for account XXXXXXXXX, UserId: XXXXXXX, Error: Duplicate firstname~yyyy-964863c382d8~3/11/2021 1:05:43 PM
```

There would be other lines with data they may not have these types of lines, but I only want to identify these 2 types of values in the Two column. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: If they are always the same number of digits preceded by the same word I think Replace using a regex would work for you.

Comment: Will they always be in that same context? Ie. account id is preceded by the text "account " and followed by a comma?

Comment: Yes they would be exactly as above - Ie. account id is preceded by the text "account " and followed by a comma and then UserId: and number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Misread the question at first..

You can import the csv and change only the identities in field `Two` like this:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TheFile.csv' -Delimiter '~'
foreach ($item in $data) {
    $item.Two =  $item.Two -replace '(account\s*)[^,]+', '$1XXXXXXXXX' -replace '(UserId:\s*)\d+', '$1XXXXXXX'
}
$data | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TheUpdatedFile.csv' -Delimiter '~' -NoTypeInformation
```

`Export-Csv` above will quote every field in the CSV
If you have PowerShell 7, you can add `-UseQuotes AsNeeded` to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet to have the fields unquoted.
For PowerShell versions below that, you can use my function [ConvertTo-CsvNoQuotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60681762/9898643) I posted earlier.

Output (with quotes)

```
"One"~"Two"~"Three"~"Four"
"Test One"~"Failed for account XXXXXXXXX, UserId: XXXXXXX, Error: Duplicate nickname"~"8abc-964863c382d8"~"3/11/2021 1:03:43 PM"
"Test One"~"Failed for account XXXXXXXXX, UserId: XXXXXXX, Error: Duplicate firstname"~"zzzz-964863c382d8"~"3/11/2021 1:04:43 PM"
"Test One"~"Failed for account XXXXXXXXX, UserId: XXXXXXX, Error: Duplicate firstname"~"yyyy-964863c382d8"~"3/11/2021 1:05:43 PM"
```

Comment: This is excellent and just what I was looking for. Studying regular expressions this weekend. You guys make this look too easy! Thanks again, marking as solved!