# Removing text qualifiers from multiple files via Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, text, txt

I've never utilised Powershell before but I'm trying to set up an easy way of removing text qualifiers that might cause skewing ( " / ' / "/,) while not having to manually go into each file to remove them. These files are either in .txt or .csv format.

Would like it to basically loop through ****all** files** at a in a filepath, remove the text qualifiers and then save the files.

Sample:

```
ID  |Description     |Date
================================
0001|"xasfdsghdfshdf"|05/02/2022
0002|abc "xyz" abc   |31/01/2022
0003|abcde"          |01/02/2022 
0004|"               |01/06/2022
```

Expected output:

```
ID  |Description   |Date
==============================
0001|xasfdsghdfshdf|05/02/2022
0002|abc xyz abc   |31/01/2022
0003|abcde         |01/02/2022 
0004|              |01/06/2022
```

Found a bit of script in an archive that ~should~ technically do this, but for the life of me I can't make it work. Would much appreciate any help! :)

```
$Folder = (Get-ChildItem -Path "YOUR_FOLDER_HERE" -Recurse -Filter *.CSV).FullName
foreach ($File in $Folder) {[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$File", [System.IO.Files]::ReadAllText("$File").Replace("`"",""))}

# Method 1 - Non-scalable
###foreach ($File in $Folder) { (Get-Content $File).replace("""," ") | Set-Content $File }
```

Comment: Please post a sample text file and desired output.

Comment: Both methods look good, so what is failing or doesn't work? Can you give more details on that?

Comment: Removing text qualifiers (`"`) in CSV files is hazardous as the quote(s) may be part of the field value itself. Also, if a field contains the csv file's delimiter character, this will lead to field-shifting making the csv file unusable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60681762/9898643)

Comment: Your ```ReadAllText``` version replaces the ```"``` character with an empty string, whereas the ```Get-Content``` version replaces it with a space. From your example output it looks like you want ```[System.IO.Files]::ReadAllText("$File").Replace("`""," "))``` to preserve column alignment - i.e. the second parameter to ```Replace``` is a space (```" "```), not an empty string (```""```)