# Timestamp issues with Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a small powershell script that pulls the last hour of punch data from a sql db, it then outputs that data to a .csv file. The script is working, but the timestamp is like this:
hh:mm:ss.xxx, i need it to be only hh:mm, Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the script and a snippet of the output:

```
sqlcmd -h-1 -S ZARIRIS\IRIS -d IA3000SDB -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; Select Distinct TTransactionLog_1.DecisionTimeInterval,
TTransactionLog_1.UserID, TTransactionLog_1.OccurDateTime, TTransactionLog_1.StableTimeInterval

From TTransactionLog_1
Inner join TSystemLog1 On TTransactionLog_1.NodeID=TSystemLog1.NodeID
Inner join TUser On TTransactionLog_1.UserID=Tuser.UserID
where TSystemLog1.NodeID = 3 and TTransactionLog_1.OccurDateTime >= dateadd(HOUR, -1, getdate())" -s  "," -W -o  "C:\atr\karen\adminreport3.csv"

Get-Content "C:\ATR\Karen\adminreport3.csv" | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "44444444","IN PUNCH"} | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "11111111","OUT PUNCH"} | Set-Content "C:\ATR\Karen\punchreport1.csv" -Force
```

Output: (where i need the hh:mm format, it needs to read 12:08, not 12:08:19.000)

```
112213,2022-10-31 12:08:19.000,OUT PUNCH
```

Comment: Does this csv have headers? Why read a csv file as an array of strings instead of having it parsed out using `Import-Csv` ?

Comment: This is the format required by ADP to upload our timeclock punches to them.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best if your script were to write out a date formatted the way you want in the first place,
but if that's not an option, you really should consider using `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` to manipulate the data inside.
If the standard quoted csv output is something you don't want, please see [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60681762/9898643) to safely remove the quotes where possible.

Having said that, here's one way of doing it in a line-by-line fashion:

```powershell
Get-Content "C:\ATR\Karen\adminreport3.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $line = $_ -replace "44444444","IN PUNCH" -replace "11111111","OUT PUNCH"
    $fields = $line -split ','
    # reformat the date by first parsing it out as DateTime object
    $fields[1] = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}' -f [datetime]::ParseExact($fields[1], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff',$null)
    # or use regex on the date and time string as alternative
    # $fields[1] = $fields[1] -replace '^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}).*', '$1'

    # rejoin the fields with a comma
    $fields -join ','
} | Set-Content "C:\ATR\Karen\punchreport1.csv" -Force
```